# Using MS Graph API without user credentials

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to **use the MS Graph API without user credentials** in console application to create tasks in MS Planner.

I've created it with user credentials, and everything seems to work, except that I can only create tasks in buckets where the user is a member of the Office 365 group.

I've followed all the steps in the dev informatie from MS:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

I'm getting a token back, but when I'm trying to create a task, I'm getting a error: "insufficient privileges to complete the operation' or "not enough permissions".

Can somebody point me in the right direction, or supply me of some working c# code to connect to the MS Graph API with AppId + SecretId

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_tasks)? If yes, this document says that application permissions are not supported.

Comment: @robdy , yeah I used that.. Did not saw that information.. Thanks for pointing that out. Do you know if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use `create PlannerTaks`, you'll see in the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_tasks) that application permissions for that (same is for beta version):

[image]

Based on that you'll have to use delegated permission to create tasks.